# Setting up MySQL server on C# deployment

Tags: c#, mysql, deployment

I have finished developing the first release of my application which uses MySQL (locally under one license and hosted under another).

Connecting the application to the hosted database works fine, i edit the connection details within my application to the hosted server details and it works fine.

However, when I try and use it locally (server:localhost etc..) i get an error stating it can not access the server. In my application, i have included the mysql DLL files, but I would prefer the user not to have to install MySQL server which is about a 100MB download (i know its quite small these days but want the install to be as pain free as possible).

I know it would be an easy fix just to add this install as a prerequisite, but i am sure there is a way to do it without this, or maybe not. Is there a script i can run which will run through and setup the server with users etc?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Shaun

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to a local mysql database implies there's a mysql database service running and was previously installed.

If you want a database you can distribute with your program without having to install a fully fledged database there are quite a few around such as [MSSQLCE](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx).

But otherwise, your user is going to have to install mysql on his own machine and keep it running.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice, do you know if i can put the MySQL server .MSI in with my installer to install at the same time, as a prerequisite. Or would I have to purchase a commercial license from Oracle to do this?

Thanks. Shaun

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use [SQLLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), which is what i have had the best experience with so far.
It should be easy to refactor your Program to use this, and it takes no user setup to use it.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have looked at SQLLite, the only problem being is that there are going to be two variants of my application, a local database - to be used just on that computer and a hosted database - so it can be used from anywhere with an internet connection. So I didn't want to have two different sets of statements for each database type, and I have also read that SQLLite isn't great with multi-access so wouldn't suit the online version of the program, although that info might be out of date.

Comment: The problem is, as far as i know, there is no free integrated mysql version.
You should possibly switch to any other DB system that offers this, like Microsoft SQLServer(server) with MSSQLCE(client backend) like @Haedrian stated.